# nginx proxy pass to a directory

Tags: nginx

I am trying to install Participad for wordpress which first requires an install of etherpad in yourdomain.com/etherpad/. I have installed etherpad correctly and it is working when I connect directly to it via ssh port forwarding. But when I reconfigure my virtual host in nginx to add:

```
location /etherpad/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
proxy_set_header    Host $host;
proxy_buffering     off;
```

Then I can not load the css file among other things which can be found under /static/custom/index.css when I connect directly to it, but through nginx I get a 404. So I can load the index page but without css (and I guess the javascript does not work either, did not even try yet.)

I am used to proxy / with nginx, not a folder. What did I miss?

Comment: If you've done what I wrote in my answer and even then it's not working, then please paste the last few entries of logs of nginx, which is by default in /var/log/nginx/error.log & /var/log/nginx/access.log. I'm on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Define location blocks for js and css like this, in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default or nginx.conf, whichever is there on your system

```
    location ~ \.js$ {
    root /pathtoJSFiles;
    }       

    location ~ \.css$ {
    root /pathtoCSSFiles;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure where ~ \.js$ and .css$ will be looking.Could you give more details please? If it is generic I can't use it because I already have a wordpress install on that same domain.

Comment: Add these location blocks in the concerned server block

Comment: paste the last few lines of error.log and access.log, that'll tell where the server is looking for .js and .css

Comment: What I'm not sure is what you are trying to do with location ~ \.js$ for instance. Does it catch all .js requests and look for a corresponding file in the path specified? because if that's the case then in this server block there will be calls to .js for the wordpress install and the js files won't be found in the specified path. Could you explain what is your intention with this location statement please?

Comment: yes, my intention is the same, but why js files won't be found in the specified path?If the path you're giving is right, then it's supposed to work fine.Please paste last few lines of logs, as I said above also.

Comment: I have not tried yet so there is no log to paste. I wanted to understand your logic before trying. As I said there is a wordpress install in this server block, which has its own path for css and javascript. If I catch all requests to .js and .css I will catch both requests to etherpad -and- to wordpress. If I understand your logic I will then send nginx to find them in the etherpad path, which won't work for worpdress. Am I right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28311/discussion-between-upasana-shukla-and-bastian)